# Root canal and filling or root canal and crown....?

Tags: dentistry, oral-health

My dentist re-implanted my avulsed front tooth 2 1/2 weeks ago and I went back yesterday and he said my tooth was healing and getting stronger and he wanted to do a root canal, clean the nerves out and put a crown on. I didn't want my tooth ground down so I told him I would wait. Is it possible to do the root canal and just fill the root with filling..?

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to just do the root canal treatment and cover that with a small composite filling on the tongue side of the tooth. My opinion is that this is the ideal way to treat the tooth assuming that there is not a big filling or a big break in the tooth right now.  (Doing a full crown over a front tooth that has a root canal greatly weakens the tooth and the patient runs a higher chance of the whole tooth breaking off at gum level.)

Comment: Welcome to Health SE! This post has the makings of a very good answer, but here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)

Comment: Ken, There was no big break other than a chip. My tooth is almost completely healed and crown on front tooth just doesn't seem right to me. Perhaps it's time for a different dentist lol

Answer (score 2):

As it is a front tooth, root canal and tooth coloured filling like composite is enough. A full crown is strongly recommended if the tooth is a back or posterior tooth in order  to survive the strong masticatory forces. A root canal filled tooth has more chances of fracture when under masticatory stress compares to natural teeth. That is why a crown is recommended. But in this case it is a front tooth, masticatory load will be less.